# Issue getting a shape from custom class to be added to driver class

Tags: java, list, class, javafx, shapes

Hey everyone I'm writing a program the is a pizza builder, it has several check boxes and whenever you click on it will add 0.50 to the total and add a shape of whatever topping user chose. I created a class called Toppings that will create several different shapes. Everything seems to work but whenever I try to create it in the driver class it keeps throwing an error. Here is some code from the Toppings class:

```
public class Toppings {

private String shapeName;
private int radius, xCoor, yCoor;

// Constructor for Toppings-------------------------------------------------
public Toppings(String shapeName, int radius, int xCoor, int yCoor) {
     this.radius = radius;
     this.xCoor = xCoor;
     this.yCoor = yCoor;
     
}

public Toppings() {
    
}

public void createPepperoni() {
    
    // Create a circle for pepperoni----------------------------------------
    Circle pepperoni = new Circle();
    pepperoni.setRadius(radius);
    pepperoni.setCenterX(xCoor);
    pepperoni.setCenterY(yCoor);
    
}
```

And here is where I'm trying to create a pepperoni in the driver class:

```
    pepperoni = new Toppings("pepp1", 50, 550, 150);
    pepperoni.createPepperoni();
    
    list.addAll(pizzaDough, pepperoni);
```

When I try it like this it gives me a runtime error at list.addAll but it is not very specific as to what the issue is. I have also tried it like this:

```
Group pizza1 = new Group(pizzaDough, pepperoni);
```

Attempting it this way has an error that says "constructor Group in class Group cannot not be applied to given types." Can anyone help figure out what I'm doing wrong? I have imported the Circle from javafx just FYI.

I adjusted my Toppings class to this:

```
public Shape createPepperoni() {
    
    // Create a circle for pepperoni----------------------------------------
    Circle pepperoni = new Circle();
    pepperoni.setRadius(radius);
    pepperoni.setCenterX(xCoor);
    pepperoni.setCenterY(yCoor);
    return new Circle(xCoor, yCoor, radius);
}
```

I'm still getting this error, "Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException."

Comment: Have you tried using the list argument constructor for `Group`?

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: *""constructor Group in class Group cannot not be applied to given types.""* What is not specific about that? The types of the values you are passing do not match the expected types.

Comment: My apologies not an expert in Java just learning

Comment: "I'm still getting this error..." -> To get debugging help for your application you need to provide the already requested minimal example and the complete stack trace for your exception formatted as code in the question.   This way somebody would be able to copy and paste the code without change to run it and the line numbers in the stack trace need to line up with those in the code provided.

Answer (score 1):

`pepperoni` is a `Toppings`.  If you want to put it in a `Group`, it would need to be a `Node` (which it is not).

You already have a method to make a node for a pepperoni.  That method creates a circle. You could make the `createPepporoni()` method return the circle it created and add that to a group, e.g. `group.add(pepperoni.createPepporoni())`.

```
public Shape createPepperoni() {
    return new Circle(xCoor, yCoor, radius);
}
```

Where the arguments of the circle constructor are class field values or constants that you have previously established values for.

There are numerous other issues with your code and design, as well as the naming strategy for identifiers in your app, which I won't discuss here at this time, but hopefully the info I provided might help solve some of your immediate issues.